# Evenly spaced tab titles in foundation 6

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Does anyone know how to get tab titles evenly spaced to fill the container automatically in Foundation 6 ?

I've tried wrapping the tabs in a grid-x , with cell large-auto added to the li class , this works on large screens but when we view on mobile - display:none gets added by JS to each li element ? removing the grid-x and cell returns it to normal.

There's nothing obvious over at Zerb Foundation docs , I'm a bit surprised i can't find much info on this.

```
<ul class="tabs" data-responsive-accordion-tabs="tabs small-accordion medium-accordion large-tabs" id="example-tabs">

<li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
<li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel3">Tab 3</a></li>
<li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel4">Tab 4</a></li>
<li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel5">Tab 5</a></li>
<li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel6">Tab 6</a></li>

</ul>

<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
<div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
<p>Tab 1 - Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
</div>
<div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
<p>Tab 2 - Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
</div>
<div class="tabs-panel" id="panel3">
<p>Tab 3 - Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
</div>
<div class="tabs-panel" id="panel4">
<p>Tab 4 - Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
</div>
<div class="tabs-panel" id="panel5">
<p>Tab 5 - Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
</div>
<div class="tabs-panel" id="panel6">
<p>Tab 6 - Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to do this.

Make the parent container, `.tabs` -> `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to spread them apart.

The children can have the flex grow property to fill in the empty space.

Example: https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/exvwrB